# Unexpected output filling an array with characters read from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

I'm trying to read a text file called input.in an array of characters representing a map. The file contains two integers N and numLifes, and the corresponding matrix. N represents the dimension of a square matrix (NxN).

I want that if N is less than 10, assign to the variable N, the value of 10 and fill the matrix 'mVill' with a '#', and then read the map file and integrate it with the matrix filled with '#'. Heres the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class hola {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char mVill[][] = null;
        int N, i,j, numLifes;
        String line=null;
        StringTokenizer tk;
        char caract;
        FileInputStream fstream = null;
        try {
            fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/input.in");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        try {
            if ((line = br.readLine()) == null) {
                System.out.print("Error empty file...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        tk = new StringTokenizer(line);
                N = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
                numLifes = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());

                int nAux=N;
                if (N<10){
                    N=10;
                    mVill = new char[N][N];
                    for (char[] row: mVill)
                        Arrays.fill(row, '#');
                    for (i=0; i <nAux; i++) {
                        for (j=0;j<nAux;j++){
                            try{
                            caract = (char) br.read();
                            mVill[i][j]=caract;
                            }catch (Exception e){
                               System.out.println("Error in read file");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    mVill = new char[N][N];
                    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                        try {
                            mVill[i] = br.readLine().toCharArray();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(N+" "+numLifes);

                for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        System.out.print(mVill[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
    }//end main
}//end class
```

For this input:

```
7 3
F..*..F
.##.##.
.#...#.
*..P..*
.#...#.
.##.##.
F..*..F
```

the output is (which is wrong):

```
F..*..F###

.##.####
#.
.#.###
..#.
*###
..P..*
###

.#...####
.
.##.###
##########
##########
##########
```

The output should I expect to receive it:

```
F..*..F###
.##.##.###
.#...#.###
*..P..*###
.#...#.###
.##.##.###
F..*..F###
##########
##########
##########
```

What am I doing wrong? I do not see any error in reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Steve's answer, the quick and dirty way to correct it would be to do this when you are reading your characters:

```
caract = (char) br.read();
while (caract == '\n' || caract == '\r') {
    caract = (char) br.read();
}
mVill[i][j]=caract;
```

So the linefeed and carriage return characters would be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not taking the carriage-return / linefeed characters into account when reading  the input.  I would probably use a different technique, where you read a line at a time rather than a single character.

Try testing the character to see if it is a cr/lf and skip it if so.